# Best practices with Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I create mocked objects and I define some rules (when `someMethod()` then `doSth()`).

What are the best practices to make that? Create a class with such functionality returning mocked object? Or make a private static method returning mocked object ? Or make my own mocked class?

Comment: Uh, just initiate a `mock(MyClass.class)`... Note that you can also stub spies (ie, `spy(new MyClass())`).

Comment: Have you looked at the [examples](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html)?

Comment: @fge I know, but I ask how to organize code if I have several when(mockedObject).thenDoSth() and several mocked objects. Whhich pattern is the best for readability and organization?

Comment: @FGreg yes, but examples are built of simple cases and several lines. I want to know how to organize more complex code.

Comment: Well, if you always use the same set of mocks you can start by creating the mocks in `@BeforeMethod` instead of in each `@Test`; also, you might want to stub in `@BeforeMethod` if you have "constant stubbings` across the test class

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you find yourself creating test classes (other than the classes containing actual tests), then you've defeated the purpose of having a mocking framework.

Create your mocks in your testcases:

```
 @Test
 public void testGreetingGenerator() {
      Person mockPerson = mock(Person.class);
      when(mockPerson.getName()).thenReturn("Alan");

      GreetingGenerator greeting = new GreetingGenerator(mockPerson);
      assertEquals("Hello Alan", greeting.getGreeting());
 }
```

If you are using the same mock in many tests, by all means make the mock a field, and put the mock creation into an `@Before` method.

```
 @Before
 public void setUp() {
      mockPerson = mock(Person.class);
      when(mockPerson.getName()).thenReturn("Alan");
 }

 @Test
 public void testGreetingGenerator() {
      GreetingGenerator greeting = new GreetingGenerator(mockPerson);
      assertEquals("Hello Alan", greeting.getGreeting());
 }
```

You can create a "basic" mock in `setUp()` and add more mocked behaviour to it in the individual testcases. Remember that `setUp()` gets called before each test, so you get fresh objects in each test.

If the mock creation gets too long and complex, it's fine to move it into a method (static or otherwise), and if necessary decompose that method into lots of smaller ones.

However, if your test code gets too complicated, think of it as a warning that perhaps the unit under test has too many dependencies and needs to be redesigned for testability.

Mocking is for **unit testing**. In the example above, the **unit** I am testing is `GreetingGenerator`. I am not intending to test `Person` here, so it is better to use a mock `Person` than a real one. That way if something about `Person` breaks, my `Person` tests will fail but my `GreetingGenerator` tests will keep working.

However that means that those tests don't validate that your Person and GreetingGenerator classes interoperate properly, and that's why *as well as* unit tests, you should have *integration tests*.

If you know a class is just for value objects, there's little benefit in using a mock.

Comment: GreetingGenerator in your code do not use mockPerson object. You should add to this example sample usage of that object.

Comment: Better is mocking what can be mocked or create real objects?

Comment: For *unit testing* it's better to have mocks; but you also need integration tests to verify your tests collaborate correctly. I added something about this.

Comment: be more creative when using `@Before` `@Test` annotations ;)
You name the method as you want like `@Before public void initialize_default_person_behavior()`. You can have multiple set-up methods.